How to handle missing ipoib driver in Ubuntu initrd during PXE installation using IB network card?
I am attempting to perform a PXE installation of Ubuntu Server and I'm encountering an issue with my InfiniBand (IB) network card. My intention is to use IP over InfiniBand (ipoib) functionality for network communication. However, during the boot process, it seems that the initial ramdisk (initrd) included with Ubuntu does not contain the necessary ipoib driver, which prevents the system from obtaining an address via DHCP and completing the PXE boot process.

You can update the initrd to add the drivers.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/1438628/376778
